# Sass nesting multiple classes

Tags: css, sass

Alright, so this is what I want to achieve:

```
.about{
  /* some styling */
}
.about,.about-pg{
  /* other styling */
}
```

Using Sass, I figured I could do

```
.about
  /* some styling */
  &,.about-pg
    /* other styling */
```

However it compiles to:

```
.about{
  /* some styling */
}
.about,.about .about-pg{
  /* other styling */
}
```

Any clue why and how to solve this?

Comment: Use a variable maybe?

Comment: @FelipeAls How would that work then? Main problem is that Sass introduces another - in this case - '.about' where I don't want it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SASS apply to only one style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382656/sass-apply-to-only-one-style)

Comment: @cimmanon he makes use of the same piece of code, yes. However, it doesn't compile right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@extend`:

```
.about
  /* some styling */
  @extend .about-pg

.about-pg
  /* other styling */
```