# I have one div that uses all the characteristics of another except for one. Using scss, is there any inheritance i could use?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am working on a project in which i need to use a small div and use all the same css characteristics of this div except for one.  The problem that i am having is that the methods i've tried are not working, and the only thing that I am left to do is completely copy the entire css class and just alter the one characteristic.  That method works, but it is not a very DRY way of doing it, and I am wondering if there is another way.

My front end is like so

```
%a.btn.button.test{ 'ui-sref' => 'visit.report({ id: visitId })' } v        Save a Spot
```

My css is like so

```
.button {
color: $button-text;
background: $button-background;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 7px;
margin-bottom: 7px;
padding: 20px;
opacity: 1;
transition: all .1s ease-in-out;

&:hover {
    color: $button-text;
    opacity: .9;
    box-shadow: 3px 4px 4px $button-hover;
}

&:focus {
    color: $button-text;
    outline: none;
}

i {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: -3px;
}
}
```

So I was just thinking that the solution to this would be to add my .test class inside the button class (I'm using scss) and the change would work out as needed.

like so:

```
  ....code

   i {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: -3px;
    }

   .test{
   width: 50%;
    }
}
```

However, that approach did not work.  As of right now the only thing i've been able to do is take everything that is in the .button class, copy it, re-name it .test, and then alter the width.  So again I am wondering if there is a much dryer way of essentially stealing one element in a class without having to re-copy the code.

Comment: Alternate duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382656/sass-apply-to-only-one-style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. You've added a style for a `.test` element *within* a `.button` element.

What you mean to say is:

```css
&.test {
  width: 50%;
}
```

which expands to:

```css
.button.test {
  width: 50%;
}
```